# How can I sort a name with a comma in Twig in alphabetical order? Ex: John Doe, CFP

Tags: twig

I'm trying to sort alphabetically by either first or last name using Twig Sort with a name that has a comma in it.

**Example**

```
John Doe, CFP
Jane Doe, MBA
```

I want to sort this alphabetically such that Jane Doe would show up first if we sorted by first name.

I've reviewed a ton of Twig documentation and everything I've read says that my sort is correct, but it doesn't seem to work at all. Everything else renders correctly, but it's the sorting that is at the heart of the issue.

```
{% for post in relationship.from|sort ((a, b) => (a.post.title.split(',')[0] <=> b.post.title.split(','))[0]) %}
```

I've also tried

```
{% for post in relationship.from|sort ((a, b) => a.post.title.split(',')[0] <=> b.post.title.split(',')[0]) %}
```

Can any Twig experts weigh in? Is my syntax just wrong? Is there a new version of Twig out?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sort nor the syntax. You'll have to provide more details, cause I'm not following. `{% for post in relationship %}`, seem to me you already have a post in the sort, but then you do `a.post.title`, what is this about?

Comment: You can see the sort is actually working in [this demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#0812f7bda1), also not sure why you are splitting the name